# Need set auto increment and reset id

Tags: php

I need to develop a application for hospital patient registration system. Three `int` are required: index `{PK auto increment}` and `opd_id` and `quiue_id`.

I need to increase the `opd_id` and `quiue_id` when each patient is registered in the system and then I need to reset `quiue_id` daily and `opd_id` monthly. How should I do it?

something like this:

```
$datez = 1;
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Colombo');
$date3 = date('h-i-s A', time());

if ($date3 = '11-59-059 PM') {
    $datez = 1 ;
} else {
    $datez++;
    echo $datez;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to show what you've actually tried and explain how it's not working.

Comment: Reformatted code

Comment: What's your exact question about this? How is setting an auto ID relted to the code you've shown?

Answer (score 0):

To check if today is first day month you can use this:

```
if(date('j') === '1') { }

xxxxxxx

}
```

And your code have a bug:

```
if ($date3 = '11-59-059 PM'){
```

You need to compare `(double =)` not to assign `(one =)`:

```
if ($date3 == '11-59-059 PM'){
```